# How can I put a delay on the closing of this ngbPopover?

Tags: angular, popover, ng-bootstrap

I am working in Angular7 using ngbootstrap. I need to delay the closing of this ngbPopover for a few seconds while i switch out the content in it and confirm the action w the user. I know how im going to handle the content but can't figure out how to delay it from the template. do i need to call it from the DOM in the .ts file? this closes it fine, but immediately. again, i want to delay the close while i show a feedback message.

was hoping i could use setTimeout in the template. no luck

According to ngbootstrap docs, the delay param/input only works when not using a manual trigger (this is considered a manual trigger by the docs) and the close method does not seem to accept and params.

```
<button
    (click)="doAThing(); myPop?.close()"
>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(click)="doAThing(myPop)"
```

in .ts:

```
doAThing(myPop) {myPop.close()}
```

here you can easily setTimeout

Comment: ngbPopover has a delay parameter: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples#delay

Comment: @Eliseo not on manual triggers it doesn't, i addressed this in my question. thanks either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
doAThing(myPop) {
myPop.closeDelay = 200;
myPop.close();
}
```